# Why does Windows sometimes start using port that I use for IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-7, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

Sometimes when I try to run the IIS Express from visual studio, I get this message:

[image]

If I check what process is using the port, I get the PID 4 which is the `System` process on my computer right now:

```
D:\>netstat -a -n -o | find "15134"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:15134          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:15134             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::1]:15134            [::1]:50081            ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    [::1]:50081            [::1]:15134            ESTABLISHED     7676

D:\>tasklist

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0         24 K
System                           4 Services                   0        304 K
```

I connected to the port on Telnet and this was the response (I just typed random letters, not a valid HTTP request):

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 15 Nov 2017 11:41:09 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 326

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/str
ict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

How to prevent this from happening? And how to deal with this problem, short of changing the development port or restarting the PC?

Comment: Just because it's listed as "System" doesn't necessarily mean it's Windows. Regardless, short of tracking down the specific application or Windows component that's using the port and either disabling it or configuring it to use a different port, there's nothing you can do. The easiest course of action is to simply change the port your web application uses, which is trivially done through the project's properties. Change it to something else, and then just get on with your day.

Answer (score 0):

PID 4 and `Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0` together mean that the port is being used by something hooked to http.sys driver.

Thus, reboot your machine is rarely a solution. Changing to another port is more realistic an option.

Note that, there can be other causes for "port is in use" issues, so this answer does not attempt to cover them all.